# logic and set theory

Tags: real-analysis

Let $S$ be a set of real numbers that is closed under multiplication. Let $T\subset S$ and $U\subset S$ such that $T\cup U= S$. Since the product of any three (not necessarily different) elements of $T$ is in $T$ and the product of any three elements of $U$ is in $U$, prove that at least one of the two subsets $T$, $U$ is closed under multiplication.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: Shouldn't "since the product..." be "if the product..."?  Certainly I can split $\Bbb R$ into two subsets such that neither is closed under threeway products.

Comment: How is that related to group theory? Is some other information given?

Comment: It's a mathematical type olympic problem for the end, it's 19 and I need to learn this, ... Since S is a set of real numbers (all the numbers on the number line, right?) It means that S can be a set of elements of natural, integer, rational and irrational numbers. Well, since I must have two disjoint subsets T and U, the most logical thing would be that the irrational numbers of S are T and the rationals are U, right? It is clear that the product of two irrationals is another irrational and that the product of two rationals not necessarily, however I do not know how to prove it ...

Comment: "It is clear that the product of two irrationals is another irrational..." Yes – clearly *wrong*.

Comment: @Martund:  I added the group theory tag because the non-zero reals form a group under multiplication.  I imagined (but now know otherwise) that $S$ would also be a group.  It might be, but not necessarily.  I'll delete it.

Comment: @Luisguamushig:  $S$ could include all of those, but it could also be all the integer powers of $2$.  It could be all the natural number powers of $2$ starting from $2^{23}$.  Both of those sets are closed under multiplication.  Say T is the one closed under multiplication.  Then T is the positive numbers in some sense and U is the negative numbers, so three U's are again negative.  The definition of positive and negative may not be the usual one.  For my powers of $2$ example $T$ could be all the even powers and $U$ could be all the odd powers.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Can you tell me why it is clearly wrong, I thought that it could be evident given that the irrationals have infinite decimals, but I see that no ... can you please explain me?

Comment: okay, I'm sorry for saying such stupidity, it is clear that the products of two irrational can be a rational, for example the root of 2 by itself or the root of six by the root of twenty-four.

Comment: i´m stupid... i´sorry

Comment: besides that the product of two rationals is always rational

Comment: I'm sorry because they had to read my stupid things

Answer (score 0):

Let S be all even numbers, T = {8}, U = S - T.
Clearly, neither T nor S is closed under product of three elements.
To rescue the problem, change "since" to "assume".